# Not understanding sybase query of type "select @variable_name , column1, column2 from TABLE_NAME"

Tags: sql, select, sap-ase

In a sybase-ase database I am working with, the following statement:

```
select distinct @RESULTSET_ID    ,
                POST_CODE        ,
                USER_ID_INSERT   ,
           from TABLE_NAME
```

... apparently puts a value into the variable `@RESULTSET_ID`.

`@RESULTSET_ID` is not a column in table `TABLE_NAME`. It is a variable, which is provided as a parameter to the stored procedure that sends the select query displayed above to the database.

I can't find anything in the docs on constructs of type `select @variable_name, column1, column2 from TABLE_NAME`. How is the value determined to which `@variable_name` is set?

Comment: Because you `set` the value before the statement executes.  The variable needs to have been `declare`d as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... you are right ... I overlooked that